# What can I return nothing if a specific condition is not true

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a Matrix class and I wrote a getNumber method which returns the number in a specific slot in the matrix. If the specific slot does not exists, what can I do? I got stuck here:

```
public int getNumber(int row, int column)
{  
    if (row < matrix.length && column < matrix[0].length) {
        return data[row][column];
    } else {
        //what now then?
    }
}
```

I don't want to return null after making the return type Integer because it doesn't feel like a nice design. What is the best way to do this? I considered ducking the IndexOutOfBoundsException but decided it is not a good idea because it doesn't change anything.

Comment: throw your own custom exception? indexoutofbounds would only really apply for accessing array indeces beyond the bounds of the array, which technically isn't happening here.

Comment: @WalterM Why do you think `-1` is not a valid number in this matrix?

Comment: @WalterM You are making a dangerous assumption that the matrix in question couldn't actually hold the value `-1`

Comment: What is wrong with returning null exactly? You can deal with the null value using a conditional whenever you call the method. Otherwise, I'd suggest returning a value that you know cannot exist in the matrix

Comment: @DaneBrick [Using and avoiding null](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)

Comment: Well, if someone downvotes every answer, then he/she should leave a note about the problem(s) in these answers.

Comment: @DaneBrick There is no such value. Any value may exist in matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your code checks bounds on the input, you should throw, rather than returning:

```
public int getNumber(int row, int column) {  
    if (row >= matrix.length || column >= matrix[0].length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("("+row+", "+column+") is not a valid pair of indexes.");
    } 
    return data[row][column];
}
```

The reason you should throw, rather than returning silently, is that exceeding bounds is a programming error. The caller should fix it by not making the call in the first place, not by checking the return value.

Comment: Why would one check the bounds if one still throw an exception? I would just use `return data[row][column];`, since the JVM will throw the exception itself, if the bounds aren't ok. Btw, your check is only halfway done.

Comment: Can you answer Tom's question which I was about to ask?

Comment: @Tom I prefer the approach of throwing deliberately, as opposed to letting JVM throw for me. I know that the other approach exists, too, so it's definitely valid to omit the check.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You prefer to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you only check for the upper bounds and "hide" the used/wrong index in the exception message? Doesn't sound like a good idea ;P. I would only throw the exception manually if I like to change the used message :).

Comment: @Tom I also throw so that I could set a breakpoint in my library in case I need to debug an invalid call. I added a custom message to the example for illustration.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm with you. Let's not get lost in the point. It is far better practice to handle things in a controlled way, even if that means raising an error rather than simply falling through to a default behavior that would raise an error anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would leave the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, making it clear in the documentation of the method.

An other way is to return an `Optional<Integer>` such that the `Optional` is empty if there is no element in the given indices.

Comment: It is better to explicit that optional works for java 8 or newer.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Only if one thinks that Libraries can't be used.

Comment: @Jean Yes but... how many uses java 1.4. Probably not many. How many use java 1.8 probably not many. So the standard is to expose a solution for most users. Explaining that is not for 1.4 is not useful, explaining that is not for 1.8 can be useful. Additionally an Optional is useful if you need an Object retrieved from a function to use somewhere. Here is not the case. Introducing a wrapper like an Optional is only adding some not useful code to show that you know how to use Optional

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Why is not useful? Every object returned is supposed to be used somewhere. ``Optional`` makes it clear that the returned object can be empty, leaving it up to the caller to handle the case the way he wants.

Comment: @Jean Logeart I suppose that in the code using the returned value no method of Optional is used (like using a default value instead of null). An Optional is very useful when you are in one of the following situations: you need to reuse that value in a collection or in a custom object not accepting nulls or you need to using functions of Optional for example to get a default value when the Optional is carrying a null. If you are not in those situations creating a wrapper is not adding nothing to the code. Only a new Object is created, but you don't use functionalities of that object

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO That is left up to the caller. For instance ``int val = matrix.getNumber(i, j).orElse(-1);``

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

- Throws an exception if the number is not retrieved
- Return an `Integer` `null` instead of an `int`. Using an Integer give you the opportunity to return a null value because Integer are standard objects and not primitive types.

Throws Exception

```
public int getNumber(int row, int column) {  
    if (row < matrix.length && column < matrix[0].length) {
        return data[row][column];
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value");
        // or throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException("Invalid value");
    }
}
```

Return a null value

```
 public Integer getNumber(int row, int column) {  
    if (row < matrix.length && column < matrix[0].length) {
        return data[row][column];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Optional or not?**
An `Optional` is a wrapper for an Object that can have the value null. Is that the right situation? I think not. There is no necessity to return a not null Object instead of null here. The code will always check the `isPresent` function, so introducing Optional only add less readability to the code, without improving it. So I don't consider an Optional as the right answer. Probably the right solution is to return an `ArrayIndexOfBoundException`

Comment: Since `null` sucks, use `Optional` instead.

Comment: Yes Optional can be an option for java 8 or newer.

Comment: Also for Java 6+ if one uses "Guava".

Comment: Not sure that an Optional is the right choose here. Optional is a container that will grant that an object is returned by the function. Here no object is needed, returning null is a better solution. Instead if you need to insert that object in a collection or map that don't accept null values an Optional is the best solution.